# How much can we compress a sequence of bits?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, intuition

Suppose that we have a sequence of bits defined for each natural less than $n$.  For example, if we have 3 bits (either 0 or 1), we can represent the sequence as a function of $x < 4$ in the following table, where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / 3}$:

$$
\begin{array}{|ccc|c|}
\hline
f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & \text{representative function} \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & \frac{\omega^{x+1} + \omega^{2(x+1)} + \omega^{3(x+1)}}{3} \\
0 & 1 & 0 & \sin{(\pi(x-1))} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 - \frac{\omega^{x} + \omega^{2x} + \omega^{3x}}{3} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\omega^{x} + \omega^{2x} + \omega^{3x}}{3} \\
1 & 0 & 1 & \sin{(\pi x)} \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 - \frac{\omega^{x+1} + \omega^{2(x+1)} + \omega^{3(x+1)}}{3} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$

What I'm wodering is, if we can use *any* function, how much can we compress a the computations for a sequence of $n$ bits, on average?

In the example above, I had trouble doing compression for roughly half of the sequences, and had to resort to roots of unity.  I'm wondering if there is a better way to compress sequences.  I have a feeling that if we could take $f(x) = ((g(x) \bmod y) \bmod z) \dots$ we would have better results.

Comment: We can use interpolation to compress whatever number of bits into functions. However, storing those functions doesn't seem that it uses less space......

Comment: Are you familiar with Reed-Solomon codes?

Comment: @BenjaminLindqvist:  I vaguely remember reading about them long ago.  I'll look into them some more.  I guess I was hoping that we could compress the calculation time, but I understand that universal compression is next to impossible :-(